# C++ window creation / SDL

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl

Simple enough question. Is there a way to achieve 'custom' windows with SDL? By this I mean, the ability to customize the application's frame / GUI / close / minimize buttons etc. Examples would be Steam, AIM/Pidgin/Hamachi. I am new to the language, and if someone could point me in the correct direction I would much appreciate it. What would the correct terminology be for this?

**Edit**: Or, just the possibility of turning off the frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With SDL, you can remove the frame by passing in `SDL_NOFRAME` to `SDL_SetVideoMode` as one of the flags.